# Simplify this function for getting and setting values

Tags: jquery, get, set

Is there a way to consolidate this function? I have about 50 similar functions, and this seems like a very cumbersome way to get and set these values.

The format of all the functions is the same: It's triggered when any of the values that it would 'get' are changed, and based on the value of the primary element *(in this case it's `Fabric_Type`)* plus the value of a few other elements, it sets the value of the target element *(i.e. `Fabric_Thickness`)*. Most of the functions get the values of the same 5 - 10 elements *(i.e. `Item` or `Lining`)*, and look for the same values in those elements (i.e. Blazers, Jackets, Outerwear). And I already have arrays set up with all the values for each element *(i.e `$Fabric_Type = array("Cashmere","Silk","Satin");`, 
`$Item = array("Blazers","Dresses","Jackets","Outerwear");`, etc.)*  :-)

What I'm trying to (in pseudo-code) is:

```
If ('Item' != Blazer, Jacket OR Outerwear AND 'Lining'!=0) OR If ('Item'=Blazer, Jacket OR Outerwear AND 'Lining'=0){'Fabric_Thickness'=2}
If ('Item' = Blazer, Jacket OR Outerwear AND 'Lining'=!0) {'Fabric_Thickness'=3}
```

jQuery:

```
$("[name=Item],[name=Fabric_Type],[name=Lining],[name=Fabric_Construction]").change(function(){  
    if( $("[name=Fabric_Type]").val() === "Satin" || $("[name=Item]").val() === "Silk"){  
            if( $("[name=Item]").val() != "Blazer" && $("[name=Item]").val() != "Jacket" && $("[name=Item]").val() != "Outerwear" && "[name=Lining]").val() != "0") || 
            ( $("[name=Item]").val() === "Blazer" || $("[name=Item]").val() === "Jacket" || $("[name=Item]").val() === "Outerwear" && "[name=Lining]").val() === "0"){
                    $('[name=Fabric_Thickness]').val('2');  
            } if( $("[name=Item]").val() === "Blazer" || $("[name=Item]").val() === "Jacket" || $("[name=Item]").val() === "Outerwear" && "[name=Lining]").val() != "0" {
                    $('[name=Fabric_Thickness]').val('3');  
            } else {
                    $('[name=Fabric_Thickness]').val('1');  
            }
    }    
});
```

Comment: @undefined - No :-) After taking 10 minutes just to convert the 1rst function I realized that there had to be a better way to go about this ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a function outside of the `change` block called isThickerFabric (or whatever name is the most correct for the domain):

```
var isThickerFabric = function() {
  var item = $("[name=Item]").val();
  return item == "Blazer" || item == "Jacket" || item == "Outerwear";
}

var hasLining = function() {
  var lining = $("[name=Lining]").val();
  return lining != "0";
}
```

Then, you can simplify the method in one of two ways:

```
$("[name=Item],[name=Fabric_Type],[name=Lining],[name=Fabric_Construction]").change(function(){  
  if ( $("[name=Fabric_Type]").val() === "Satin" ) {
    var fabricThicknessElement = $('[name=Fabric_Thickness]');

    if ( isThickerFabric() && !hasLining || !isThickerFabric() && hasLining ) {
      fabricThicknessElement.val('2');
    } else if ( isThickerFabric() && hasLining() ) {
      fabricThicknessElement.val('3');
    } else {
      fabricThicknessElement.val('1');
    }
  }    
});
```

Or, sometimes, when I have a couple of binary properties as you do here, I find it valuable to "keep score" instead:

```
$("[name=Item],[name=Fabric_Type],[name=Lining],[name=Fabric_Construction]").change(function(){  
  if ( $("[name=Fabric_Type]").val() === "Satin" ) {
    var fabricThicknessElement = $('[name=Fabric_Thickness]');

    var thicknessScore = 1;
    if ( hasLining() ) {
      thicknessScore++;
    }

    if ( isThickerFabric() ) {
      thicknessScore++;
    }

    $('[name=Fabric_Thickness]').val(thicknessScore);
  }
});
```

Comment: That's amazing :-D The 1rst answer is nice and simple and does exactly what I wanted :-D I'm also intrigued by the 2nd method because it might be an even better approach for me to take, considering some of the other aspects of this form... Would you mind explaining it a bit, and why you find it helpful to 'keep score' that way? Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but most of the questions 'get' values from 4 - 8 elements, and then depending upon the value of the primary element, 1 of apx. 6 different scenarios is applied.

Comment: I realized that I could streamline it a little more by defining 'var fabricThicknessElement' outside of the function as well :-D

Comment: The part of the function that identifies if there is a lining isn't working properly. I can't figure out why, but it results in the wrong answer (I'm not sure exactly what's happening, but it looks like it's giving the value for the next equation). I've posted a fiddle so you can see what I'm referring to http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/9NKjT/1/

Comment: I modified the syntax a bit and it's now working perfectly, and I've updated the answer :-)

Comment: About keeping score.  Let's say that you are mixing colors.  You can imagine the complicated if statements that would be needed to determine the outcome, e.g. if ( blue && red ) { purple } else if ( red && white ) { pink } else if...  Really, if we can quantify (give a score to) each option the user chooses, then we don't need complicated conditional logic, e.g. if ( red ) colorValue += "AA0000";  if ( blue ) colorValue += "0000AA";, etc.

Comment: This sounds really interesting and I think it would be a much smarter way for me to do this because the full if statement is actually a lot more complicated than the snippet I posted :-) But I'm having a bit of trouble connecting your explanation for mixing colors to the code in your 2nd answer for thicknessScore. Would you mind elaborating a bit?